# Python colorbar with errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, errorbar

I am trying to plot x vs y data and trying to see the variation of x and y with respect to z using a colorbar.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
x_err = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
y = [5,6,7,8,9]
y_err = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]
z = [3,4,5,6,7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar(x, y, x_err, y_err, fmt='*', elinewidth = 0.9, ecolor='black')

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=5)
cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter,cmap='viridis')
cbar.set_label('z')
```

I need the errorbar to have the same color as that of the datapoint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the `ecolor` from the same cmap. Not sure there aren't any solution to do that for you, but it doesn't cost much

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
x_err = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
y = [5,6,7,8,9]
y_err = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]
z = [3,4,5,6,7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Rest of your code is yours. Only this line is added (and next line modified to use this "col" as ecolor
col=cm.viridis((np.array(z)-min(z))/(max(z)-min(z))) # RGBA colors from z
ax.errorbar(x, y, x_err, y_err, ecolor=col, fmt='*', elinewidth = 0.9)

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=5)
cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter,cmap='viridis')
cbar.set_label('z')

plt.show()
```

Result
[image]